# SHA-1 is not working in Firebase as it generates an message, can you tell me how to obatin new SHA-1?

Tags: android, firebase, sha

I am trying to add my android project to Firebase. I got the SHA-1 from my project but when I put it in Firebase the following error message appeared: An unexpected error has occurred. [Reason: Requested entity already exists]. I have already used this SHA-1 in a previous project. What should I do to resolve this issue? Is it possible to generate another SHA-1? If so, how?

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with your firebase projects setup. Could you elaborate more? A given keystore has only 1 SHA1 representation. So no, you cant generate another SHA1. Are you trying to use two firebase projects for the same app? It would help if you could explain your use case.

Comment: @henry OK well let me try to explain. I have completed an app and I am trying to add a login facility with Firebase through following a codelab [https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-login#3].  In my Firebase account I added a new project and gave it a name. On the next screen you are required to put in the SHA 1 certificate number to proceed. So to do this I followed the guidance from google in this link [https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth]. Once I got the number, I filled in the field with it and then I got this error message.